# Laravel 4: prevent lazy load hasMany relation when foreign_key is null (optional relation)

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I've got a hasMany relationship defined this way, in a `Command` Eloquent model:

```
public function rows()
{
   return $this->hasMany('\Acme\Models\Row')
}
```

In my case, rows **can** be linked to Commands, or not. So my `Row` migration file contains a nullable foreign key:

```
$table->integer('command_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->index();
$table->foreign('command_id')->references('id')->on('commands')->onDelete('set null');
```

Nothing really crazy.

I realize thought that if I instantiate a new `Command` object and call `$command->rows`, instead of an empty Collection, I get all the rows with a null `command_id`.

This is perfectly explained by the SQL generated by this `$command->rows` call:

```
select * from `rows` where `rows`.`command_id` is null
```

I think it's strange that Laravel choose to consider valid a null foreign key... What do you think: is this a bug? Am I missing something? What could be the best way to prevent this behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: That **is** odd behaviour. I'm tempted to call this a bug. After all, in SQL `null <> null`, so a join on two `null` values would not return any values. What Eloquent is doing here is just weird.

Comment: I'd post this on Github at Laravel/Framework and see what Taylor says...

Comment: OK, posted as an issue in the Github repo, here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5289

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 ways of handling this:

**1** In order to prevent that behaviour, with your current setup, you need to add `not null` clause on the relation definition:

```
public function rows()
{
   return $this->hasMany('\Acme\Models\Row')->whereNotNull('rows.command_id');
}
```

**2** You can also change your schema, so the foreign key is not nullable, but `Rows` without `Command` will have `0` value there.

---

Now, I think this is correct behaviour by all means. You are trying to fetch something, given `null` as prerequisite, so it finds those rows. This is unexpected in terms of business logic, but definitely not wrong.

Not mentioning that I can't think, why you would like to call relation on newly instantiated model, that clearly doesn't have any. Unless it's just curiosity.

Comment: First, thanks for your clean and simple first solution. I'll use it, since it keeps the problem on the Model; regarding your last comment, I can explain: I'm working on a generic content management tool, and in creation cases forms are populated with transient objects. My problem was that the creation form for a new Command (in this example) starts with some Rows because of the null relation.

Comment: Oh I see. fair enough.